# Seperating a character string

Tags: excel, vba

I want to separate a character string using the special characters in that string as cutting lines. After each division the next group of strings should be copied in the next column. The picture below shows how it should work.

[image]

My first approach doesn't work and maybe it's too complicated. Is there a simple solution to this task?

```
Sub SeparateString()

Dim i, j, k, counterA, counterB As Integer
Dim str1, str2 As String
Const Sonderz As String = "^!§$%&/()=?`*'_:;°,.-#+´ß}][{³²"
   
For i = 1 To Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    counterA = 0

    For j = 1 To Len(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & i))
    
        counterB = 0
        
        For k = 1 To Len(Sonderz)
        
            If Mid(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & i), j, 1) = Mid(Sonderz, k, 1) Then
        
                counterA = counterA + 1
        
            End If
            
            If Mid(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & i), j, 1) <> Mid(Sonderz, k, 1) And counterA = 0 And counterB = 0 Then
                                                   
                Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B" & i) = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B" & i) & Mid(Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & i), j, 1)
                
                counterB = counterB + 1

            End If

        Next k
    
    Next j
       
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `Split` function?  See [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-10/aa155763(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Could the delimiters be any of those characters in any cell in any combination?

Comment: Your sample data is strangely consistent but your code suggests otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested and you do have access to Microsoft 365's dynamic arrays:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(X,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML(CONCAT("<t><s>",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(X,"^!§$%&/()=?`*'_:;°,.-#+´ß}][{³²")),"</s><s>",X),"</s></t>"),"//s")))
```

Or nest a `SUBSTITUTE()` if you need to return string variables:

[image]

```
=LET(X,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML(CONCAT("<t><s>'",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(X,"^!§$%&/()=?`*'_:;°,.-#+´ß}][{³²")),"</s><s>'",X),"</s></t>"),"//s"),"'","")))
```

---

If VBA is a must, you could think about a regular expression to replace all the characters from a certain class with a uniform delimiter to use `Split()` on:

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = "CD!02?WX12EF"
Dim arr() As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[!§$%&\/()=?`*'_:;°,.#+´ß}\][{³²^-]"
    arr = Split(.Replace(s, "!"), "!")
End With

For Each el In arr
    Debug.Print el
Next

End Sub
```

The caret has been moved from being the 1st character to any but the first to prevent a negated-character class; also the hyphen has been moved to the back to prevent an array-construct of characters. Funny enough, if you actually want to be less verbose you could throw these character in a more condense class `` [!#-/:;?[]-`{}§=°´ß³²] ``.

Comment: Might be easier to use negation instead and just list the acceptable characters. For example, `\W+` for the pattern. Or if you don't want the underscore as an acceptable character `[^A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, yeah I thought about that but since I don't know if the data in between the delimiters would fall in alphanumeric ranges I left it out. As it is, the sample data does seem to represent all possible cases (looking at which delimiters OP has). Good comment though!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first data is in cell A2,
I would go with the simple use of find() with left() mid() and right()

```
=left(A2,find("!",A2,1)-1)
```

then:

```
=mid(A2,find("!",A2,1)+1,find("?",A2,1)-find("!",A2,1)-1)
```

and:

```
=right(A2,len(A2)-find("?",A2,1))
```

Tested and working with one correction done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in Power Query which has a command to split by ANY delimiter.

In the code below, I generate a list of all possible special characters defined as characters NOT in the set of `A..Za..z0..9` and you can easily add to that list by editing the code if you want to include other characters in the permitted list.

***Edit:** If you only have a few special characters, you can just hard-code the list, eg `{"!","?"}` instead of using `List.Generate`, but in your question you did not necessarily restrict the list of special characters, even though those are the only two showing in your examples*

To use Power Query:

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//change Table name in next line to reflect actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table15"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Source", type text}}),

//Generate list of "special characters" for splitting
//the List.Contains function contains the non-special characters
splitterList = List.RemoveNulls(
    List.Generate(()=>0,
        each _ <= 255,
        each _ +1,
        each if List.Contains({"A".."Z","a".."z","0".."9"}, Character.FromNumber(_)) then null else Character.FromNumber(_))),

    splitIt = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Source", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter(splitterList))
in
    splitIt
```

[image]